# FFMPEG "Could not allocate memory" Errors through php

Tags: php, linux, video, encoding, ffmpeg

I've tried to find a solution online for days now but cannot find any solution.

I just switched server (Intel Xeon to AMD) and since the switch I've not been able to get ffmpeg conversions working through the php script. ffmpeg was the exact same version and all php settings are set.

All commands that the script executes (copied from log files) were tried in shell and executed with no problems.

The errors look like this:

```
[124] =>       handler_name    : Video Media Handler
    [125] =>     Stream #8:1(eng): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 160 kb/s (default)
    [126] =>     Metadata:
    [127] =>       handler_name    : Sound Media Handler
    [128] => Stream mapping:
    [129] =>   Stream #0:0 (h264) -> concat:in0:v0
    [130] =>   Stream #1:0 (h264) -> concat:in1:v0
    [131] =>   Stream #2:0 (h264) -> concat:in2:v0
    [132] =>   Stream #3:0 (h264) -> concat:in3:v0
    [133] =>   Stream #4:0 (h264) -> concat:in4:v0
    [134] =>   Stream #5:0 (h264) -> concat:in5:v0
    [135] =>   Stream #6:0 (h264) -> concat:in6:v0
    [136] =>   Stream #7:0 (h264) -> concat:in7:v0
    [137] =>   scale -> Stream #0:0 (libvpx)
    [138] => Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
    [139] => [h264 @ 0x34f1dc0] get_buffer() failed
    [140] => [h264 @ 0x34f1dc0] thread_get_buffer() failed
    [141] => [h264 @ 0x34f1dc0] decode_slice_header error
    [142] => [h264 @ 0x34f1dc0] no frame!
    [143] => [h264 @ 0x350e680] Error splitting the input into NAL units.
    [144] => [h264 @ 0x352af40] Cannot allocate memory.
    [145] => [h264 @ 0x352af40] Could not allocate memory
    [146] => [h264 @ 0x352af40] h264_slice_header_init() failedError while decoding stream #0:0: Cannot allocate memory
    [147] => [h264 @ 0x352af40] Cannot allocate memory.
    [148] => [h264 @ 0x352af40] Could not allocate memory
    [149] => [h264 @ 0x352af40] h264_slice_header_init() failedError while decoding stream #0:0: Cannot allocate memory
    [150] => [h264 @ 0x352af40] Cannot allocate memory.
    [151] => [h264 @ 0x352af40] Could not allocate memory
    [152] => [h264 @ 0x352af40] h264_slice_header_init() failedError while decoding stream #0:0: Cannot allocate memory
    [153] => [h264 @ 0x352af40] Cannot allocate memory.
    [154] => [h264 @ 0x352af40] Could not allocate memory
    [155] => [h264 @ 0x352af40] h264_slice_header_init() failedError while decoding stream #0:0: Cannot allocate memory
    [156] => [h264 @ 0x352af40] Cannot allocate memory.
    [157] => [h264 @ 0x352af40] Could not allocate memory
...
..
  [211519] => [h264 @ 0x886a3c0] h264_slice_header_init() failedToo many errors when draining, this is a bug. Stop draining and force EOF.
    [211520] => Error while decoding stream #7:0: Internal bug, should not have happened
    [211521] => Cannot allocate memory.
    [211522] => sws: initFilter failed
    [211523] => [Parsed_scale_1 @ 0x8e0be40] Failed to configure output pad on Parsed_scale_1
    [211524] => Error reinitializing filters!
    [211525] => Error while filtering: Operation not permitted
    [211526] => Finishing stream 0:0 without any data written to it.
    [211527] => [libvpx @ 0x6f4c600] v1.8.1-301-g89375f031
    [211528] => Output #0, webm, to '/home/website/public_html/media/videos/tmb/2420/video_copy.webm':
    [211529] =>   Metadata:
    [211530] =>     major_brand     : isom
    [211531] =>     minor_version   : 512
    [211532] =>     compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    [211533] =>     title           : Aibeya The Animation
    [211534] =>     encoder         : Lavf58.35.100
    [211535] =>     Chapter #0:0: start 0.000000, end 102.102000
    [211536] =>     Metadata:
    [211537] =>       title           : Intro
    [211538] =>     Chapter #0:1: start 102.102000, end 110.369000
    [211539] =>     Metadata:
    [211540] =>       title           : Title
    [211541] =>     Chapter #0:2: start 110.369000, end 312.179000
    [211542] =>     Metadata:
    [211543] =>       title           : Part 1
    [211544] =>     Chapter #0:3: start 312.179000, end 548.415000
    [211545] =>     Metadata:
    [211546] =>       title           : Part 2
    [211547] =>     Chapter #0:4: start 548.415000, end 706.831000
    [211548] =>     Metadata:
    [211549] =>       title           : Part 3
    [211550] =>     Chapter #0:5: start 706.831000, end 1011.052000
    [211551] =>     Metadata:
    [211552] =>       title           : Part 4
    [211553] =>     Chapter #0:6: start 1011.052000, end 1198.823000
    [211554] =>     Metadata:
    [211555] =>       title           : Part 5
    [211556] =>     Chapter #0:7: start 1198.823000, end 1501.408000
    [211557] =>     Metadata:
    [211558] =>       title           : Part 6
    [211559] =>     Chapter #0:8: start 1501.408000, end 1579.945000
    [211560] =>     Metadata:
    [211561] =>       title           : Part 7
    [211562] =>     Chapter #0:9: start 1579.945000, end 1654.293000
    [211563] =>     Metadata:
    [211564] =>       title           : Ending
    [211565] =>     Stream #0:0: Video: vp8 (libvpx), yuv420p, 400x240 [SAR 837:785 DAR 279:157], q=10-42, 250 kb/s, 23.98 fps, 1k tbn, 23.98 tbc (default)
    [211566] =>     Metadata:
    [211567] =>       encoder         : Lavc58.64.101 libvpx
    [211568] =>     Side data:
    [211569] =>       cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 0/0/0 buffer size: 600000 vbv_delay: N/A
    [211570] => frame=    0 fps=0.0 q=0.0 Lsize=       1kB time=00:00:00.00 bitrate=N/A speed=   0x
    [211571] => video:0kB audio:0kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: unknown
    [211572] => Output file is empty, nothing was encoded (check -ss / -t / -frames parameters if used)
    [211573] => Conversion failed!
)
```

Command example used:

```
ffmpeg_command is /usr/local/bin/ffmpeg -ss 100 -t 1 -i /home/website/public_html/media/videos/iphone/2407.mp4 -ss 197 -t 2 -i /home/website/public_html/media/videos/iphone/2407.mp4 -ss 294 -t 3 -i /home/website/public_html/media/videos/iphone/2407.mp4 -ss 391 -t 3 -i /home/website/public_html/media/videos/iphone/2407.mp4 -ss 488 -t 3 -i /home/website/public_html/media/videos/iphone/2407.mp4 -ss 585 -t 3 -i /home/website/public_html/media/videos/iphone/2407.mp4 -ss 682 -t 3 -i /home/website/public_html/media/videos/iphone/2407.mp4 -ss 779 -t 3 -i /home/website/public_html/media/videos/iphone/2407.mp4 -ss 876 -t 3 -i /home/website/public_html/media/videos/iphone/2407.mp4 -filter_complex "[0][1][2][3][4][5][6][7]concat=n=8:v=1:a=0",scale=400:240 -codec:v libx264 -unsharp -b:v 250k -maxrate 250k -bufsize 600k -qmin 10 -qmax 42 -threads 4 -an -y /home/website/public_html/media/videos/tmb/2407/video_copy.mp4
```

**PHP Info:**
PHP 5.6
memory_limit 2001M
max_execution_time 7200
upload_max_filesize 2000M
post_max_size 2000M
max_input_time 7200
exec is not disabled

**Server info**
CentOS Linux 7 (Core)
ADVANCE-4 - AMD Epyc 7351P - 128GB DDR4 ECC 2400MHz - 2x HDD SATA 4TB Datacenter Class + 2x SSD NVMe 500GB Enterprise Class Soft RAID

All help is really appreciated! Thanks in advance

Comment: Show the full log and try increasing your `memory_limit`.

Comment: memory limit is already high enough, I'm only trying to create a 5mb video file. Here is a full log: https://pastebin.com/Bv0hQher

Comment: I doubt this is an issue specific to `ffmpeg`. Check for any limits pertaining to the user/group executing the PHP script in `/etc/security/limits.conf`. Or contact your host.